# How to use USING postgre JOIN in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I have a raw postgresql query below :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id)
a.first_name as name, b.slug as slug, b.name as property_name, 
d.building_area as building_area, e.address as address

FROM   developers c
JOIN properties b USING (id)
JOIN users a USING (id)
JOIN forms f USING (id)
JOIN property_types d USING (id)
JOIN property_items e USING (id)
WHERE b.developer_id = ".$developer['id']."
AND b.created_at >= '01-01-2017' AND b.created_at <= '01-01-2018'
ORDER  BY c.id, b.name, a.id, a.first_name
LIMIT 5
```

How do I change it to Laravel eloquent? I want to use `mutator` function to change the response data, after execution of the query.

I have tried like this :

```
$z = Developer::select(DB::raw('
DISTINCT ON (c.id)
a.first_name as name, b.slug as slug, b.name as property_name, 
d.building_area as building_area, e.address as address
            '))
->join(DB::raw('JOIN properties b USING (id)'))
->join(DB::raw('JOIN users a USING (id)'))
->join(DB::raw('JOIN forms f USING (id)'))
->join(DB::raw('JOIN property_types d USING (id)'))
->join(DB::raw('JOIN property_items e USING (id)'))
->get();
```

but laravel said :

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(),

Any idea?

Any help will be appreciated :D

Thanks

Comment: Better to write your joining clauses as `JOIN properties b ON (c.id = b.id)`

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation of the join function to see what is the argument you are missing? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins I mean, the error message is quite explicit...

Comment: Maybe 

   <code> $results = DB::select( DB::raw("
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id)
a.first_name as name, b.slug as slug, b.name as property_name, 
d.building_area as building_area, e.address as address
FROM   developers c
JOIN properties b USING (id)
JOIN users a USING (id)
JOIN forms f USING (id)
JOIN property_types d USING (id)
JOIN property_items e USING (id)
WHERE b.developer_id = ".$developer['id']."
AND b.created_at >= '01-01-2017' AND b.created_at <= '01-01-2018'
ORDER  BY c.id, b.name, a.id, a.first_name
LIMIT 5
'") );</code>

Comment: well @Cezary, i've tried that way, result is good, but i want the result is collection, so if the result is collection, i can use the `mutator` to custom the result..... if i try `DB::select("my query above")->pluck('pluck')` i got message `method pluck on array`...

Comment: @Amarnasan yes, i always read the docs before i ask here, but i'm affraid because my query is not give detail the relation between primary and foreign, because i use the `USING` clause, if my query is standart join, it will be work like a charm